# System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Login method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Id,Mail,Pass")] LoginMember member)
    {
        if (!(ModelState.IsValidField("Mail") && ModelState.IsValidField("Pass")))
        {
            return View(login);
        }

        var areThere = db.LoginMember.Any(x => x.Mail == member.Mail && x.Sifre == member.Sifre);

        if (areThere)
        {
            var name = db.LoginMember.Where(x => x.Id == member.Id).Select(x => x.Name);

            Session["login"] = name;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
        }
    }
```

This method is running, session is creating "Session["login"] = name;" and going to "return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");".

Index view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@Session["login"]

<html>Index</html>
```

When Index view is running, has an error that is "System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.", what is the wrong?

Comment: It sounds like `db` has been disposed.

Comment: db is using other views and controllers.

Comment: @Sss other controllers use difference connection

Comment: @JeffreyZhang what you did mean?

Comment: @Sss it means that your comment doesn't make much sense unless it was a typo. Why (and how) would an `ObjectContext` hold a reference to a view??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem lies here...

```
var name = db.LoginMember.Where(x => x.Id == member.Id).Select(x => x.Name);
```

the return value from `Where` and `Select` still holds a reference to the `ObjectContext`, remember that these extension methods are implemented by using deferred execution, the query is not executed until you enumerate it. Then when you save the `IEnumarable` object to a session variable and then "return" from the controller's action method, the `ObjectContext` is gargabe collected because supposedly it's no longer needed. So, basically once the view engine is rendering the Index view your session variable is holding a disposed object...hence the exception when you try to access it.

To fix the issue, you will need to "resolve" that Linq expression. I'd suggest using `FirstOrDefault` since you are only expecting one (and only one) user...

```
var user = db.LoginMember.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == member.Id);
var username = user != null ? user.Name : string.Empty;
```

the above is even safer and you can guarantee that if the user is not found `FirstOrDefault` will not throw an exception